# 'User not found exception' while accessing AWS API gateway

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, google-authentication, amazon-cognito

While accessing the AWS API gateway, I am getting the following error:

```
com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientException:  {"errorMessage":"[NotFoundException]:'User not found: us-east-1:fb********6a'"} (Service: MyClient; Status Code: 500; Error Code: null; Request ID: 20*****e97)
01-30 16:21:59.367 24265-24598/com.myaws.android W/System.err:     at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientHandler.handleResponse(ApiClientHandler.java:267)
01-30 16:21:59.367 24265-24598/com.myaws.android W/System.err:     at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientHandler.invoke(ApiClientHandler.java:94)
01-30 16:21:59.367 24265-24598/com.myaws.android W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
01-30 16:21:59.367 24265-24598/com.myaws.android W/System.err:     at $Proxy1.apiTeamRolesGet()
01-30 16:21:59.367 24265-24598/com.myaws.android W/System.err:     at com.myaws.android.MainActivity.performAws(MainActivity.java:323)
01-30 16:21:59.367 24265-24598/com.myaws.android W/System.err:     at com.myaws.android.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:55)
01-30 16:21:59.368 24265-24598/com.myaws.android W/System.err:     at com.myaws.android.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:213)
```

Here is my code where how I am accessing them.
`onClick()` function when a method is invoked

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                performAws();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Below is the `performAws()` method:

```
private void performAws() {
    try {
        AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(MainActivity.this);
        Account[] accounts = am.getAccountsByType(GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE);

        String clientId = GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID;
        String scope = "audience:server:client_id:" + clientId;

        //Retrieve the google token
        String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), accounts[0].name, scope);

        //Set the google token in map
        Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<>();
        logins.put("accounts.google.com", token);

        //Initialize amazon cognito credentials provider
        CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                MainActivity.this, // Context
                IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
                Regions.US_EAST_1 // Region
        );

        //Set the google credentials
        credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);

        //retrieve amazon cognito id
        String cognitoId = credentialsProvider.getIdentityId();
        Log.d("MainActivity", "cognitoId = " + cognitoId);

        ApiClientFactory factory = new ApiClientFactory()
                .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
                .region("us-east-1")
                .apiKey(cognitoId);


        final MyClient myClient = factory.build((MyClient .class));
        myClient .apiTeamRolesGet();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is my `MyClient` class file:

```
@com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.annotation.Service(endpoint = "https://abc.xyz.com")
public interface MyClient{
    /**
    * @return void
    */
    @com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.annotation.Operation(path = "/api/teamRoles", method = "GET")
        void apiTeamRolesGet();

}
```

Comment: Have you tried turning on logging in your API? Have you used the test invoke functionality to ensure basic functionality?

Comment: How to check logging functionality in API?

Comment: And there is no 'execute: invoke' functionality in Role policy. Is it creating problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use test invocation functionality to test your api independently of the client code:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-test-method.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/test-invoke-method.html

You can also enable logging to get more information about the failures:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudwatch-logs/